# Is the optimal substructure property necessary to guarantee the existence of a greedy algorithm that always finds the optimal result?

Tags: greedy-algorithms

I'm trying to understand what is necessary to guarantee that a problem has a greedy algorithm that always produces optimal solutions.

In multiple places I find that a greedy algorithm can be constructed to find the optimal solution if the problem has two properties:

- Optimal substructure
- Greedy choice

There is one thing that I noticed about this that seems odd to me.

To me, a problem that satisfies the greedy choice property seems to mean:

1. The problem can be formulated as decision between options, where deciding an option will reveal exactly one new subproblem that is dependent on which option we chose. (Look at the knapsack problem for instance, after choosing an item, the next subproblem will be a decision between all the remaining items, whatever "the remaining items" are, is dependent on which item we chose.)
2. There exists some simple comparison that, by only looking at the options of the current subproblem, will always choose the option that is part of the sequence of optimal decisions.

Given this (maybe flawed) interpretation. It seems like the greedy choice property is all that's necessary for there to exist a greedy algorithm that guarantees optimal result. To me it looks like the greedy choice property is literally saying: "A problem has the greedy choice property when there exists greedy algorithm that will always return the optimal result"

If this is the case, what does the optimal substructure property add? Why it it mentioned everywhere? Is it the case that when a problem has the greedy choice property, it must also have the optimal substructure property? Does any of this make sense?

Comment: The optimal substructure property is tremendously helpful for finding situations in which a greedy choice might be optimal, and in proving that a greedy algorithm is sound.